# When Users Select a Ship Date During Holiday

Tags: forms, input, e-commerce, dates, calendar

In a shopping cart where a user can select their preferred ship date, how would you alert them when a date is a holiday or weekend? Would you use processing to not allow it? Add an alert that it would arrive the next business day? Have a notification prior to selecting the date?

Answer (score 8):

I would show a calendar picker with non-selectable days grayed out.  When the user hovers over the non-selectable day, I would display a tool tip explaining why that date isn't selectable.

For instance, here's an example of blackout dates from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates.aspx):

[image]

(Sidenote: Are you sure there's a reason for having the user select their shipping date?  In most e-commerce type applications that I've seen, the users almost invariably want their shipments as soon as possible.)

Comment: +1. That said, there is an issue with this design insofar as it wouldn't really work when holiday days are a *poor* but not *forbidden* choice. No other alternatives come to mind, though.

Comment: @Jimmy Sure, although you could simply create another design pattern that highlights unwise selections is a different way (and provides the requisite tool tip on mouseover explaining why that selection is unwise), but still allows the unwise selection to be made.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason to be able to specify a ship date, or rather a "receipt" date: when you have to be home to receive the product... Online retailers that sell items that do not fit through the letterbox really should all offer this, preferably with a morning/afternoon/evening specification in addition to the date.

Comment: @Marjan Ah, yes... receipt/delivery date makes total sense to me (and a good example of when this type of interface would be needed).

Comment: Ultimately, I think it is decided that most customers should understand when packages would, and would not arrive, alleviating any unnecessary complexity by just not doing anything.

Comment: There is also a need when customers purchase millions of products at once but don't want everything stored on site. They need to select a shipping schedule but want the bulk discounts.

Comment: @RandomBrad This is a great point... I was thinking entirely B2C, not B2B.

Comment: How come you want to let the users make poor choices? Or, who are the holidays poor for? And in what way?

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense to show the dates as a calendar, as it can be fairly self-explanatory means of indicating weekends and holidays up front, without too much extra messaging.

I've shown an example from an online grocery site in the UK called [Ocado](http://www.ocado.com/webshop/startWebshop.do). When picking dates there's a help icon above the calendar pops open a legend to explain the shading on dates. This might work for you.

[image]

Comment: I like this, but the help overlay is placed half over the calendar itself, so if the key you were interested in was on the right hand side of the calendar, it's now obscured by the help you were looking for. I would move the help to the right a bit.

Comment: I would suggest to keep the legends upfront for clear and quick view

Answer (score 1):

Six colours seem a lot of different options just to chose a date.
We (it is a calendar where users can chose a date for a service) use simple traffic light logic. Green bookable, red booked (additionally crossing out might be necessary for the colour blind) and grey not possible to book (weekends and so on). Hoover on selection.
We just had a round of user tests on some other issues and the calendar and didn't see any necessity to explain the colours.